# Invalid Network ! when using sepolia test net

Tags: solidity, web3js, ethers.js, dapps, sepolia

I have currently building DAPP project and I am using the sepolia test net with metamask.
I do have sepolia network in my metamask and the smart contract is also works.
The Problem is when we trying to connect the frontend with the backend.'

```js
    var provider = new ethers.providers.Web3Provider(
      web3.currentProvider,
      "sepolia"
    );
```

But when I change the the network from the sepolia to goerli  the error gets resolved, But i am not having enough ethers to deploy from goerli and most faucets are not working for me.[image]

Answer (score 2):

Try downgrading your ethers version. I know there are numerous problems in connecting with Sepolia > 6, so try a popular version such as 5.7.2

Comment: thx, I downgrade ethers from 6.3.0 to 5.7.2 and now I can connect to Sepolia test net

Answer (score 0):

How your `web3` object is configured currently? Maybe that object currently doesn't contain the relevant information for connecting to the Sepolia network.

You could also try instantiating your provider without `web3`:

`var provider = ethers.getDefaultProvider("sepolia");`

Other options involve using Infura or Alchemy keys directly in Ethers.

Regarding Goerli faucets, try this one, usually works for me though requires some patience:

https://goerli-faucet.pk910.de/

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).